# Simple API crawler in JS is not working

Tags: javascript, api

I just can't understand why I am getting as a ticket ~1100USD and not ~4300. 
See current ticker:

```
{"btcusd":{"high":"4380.15","low":"4205.38","volume":"5577.65704","last":"4286.85","bid":"4286.85","ask":"4290.85"}
```

Here is my code:

```
var urlLakeBtc = "https://api.LakeBTC.com/api_v2/ticker";
request(
    {
        url: urlLakeBtc,
        json: true
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var valuesArray = [];
            for (var key in body) {
                var obj = body[key];
                var currency2 = key;
                var buy = obj.ask;
                var sell = obj.bid;

                valuesArray.push([15, 'BTC', currency2, buy, sell]);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

So the question is, why are my `obj.ask` and `obj.bid` wrong for `currency2 = btcusd`?

Comment: it's a little bit unclear what's the issue

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: not sure what `request` is, but https://jsfiddle.net/7rdur6gt/ shows your logic is sound(ish)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time!
I think i've found the mistake being

                     var currency1 = key.substr(0,2);
                    var currency2 = key.substr(3,5);

Comment: You only want btcusd?